# How to assign a value to only one property of a class-array?

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have a class and an array. The array is declared as type: Class.

```
//Class
public class TestClass
{
    public int testint { get; set; }
        public string teststr { get; set; }
    public TestClass( int _testint, string _teststr )
    {
        testint = _testint;
            teststr = _teststr;
    }
}

//Array declaration
TestClass[] MyArray = new TestClass[ 3 ];
```

Now what I want to do (this is only for testing - I have a much larger code in mind when using this method I want to work):

I wanna be able to set ONLY teststr or ONLY testint of an array-cell, like so:

```
MyArray[ 0 ].testint = 3;
```

This does not return any errors, but if I try to print this; the result is blank (null - empty).

I'm using Blend 4 with Silverlight - please help if you know how to assign single properties like I want to here!

Comment: I am surprised that you don't have a null pointer exception...
try to do `MyArray[0] = new TestClass(){testint = 3}` instead.

Comment: I hope that the much larger code you have in mind has property names capitalized.

Comment: @Thomas : I guess this is because this code take part in some binding mechanism (see Blend 4 with Silverlight), and so the NullPointerException should be handled by the UI.

Comment: @Thomas: That doesn't work as TestClass() requires arguments to fall through without errors.. error CS1729 and error CS1922 is showing with the code you provided

Comment: You are rigth, so I think @Scorpi0 give you the thing, the exception should be handled by the Framework. Can you had a default parameterless constructor? Then apply the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create an instance of your TestClass, because you have just created an empty array, ie the array have 3 references to nothing.

```
TestClass[] MyArray = new TestClass[ 3 ];
```

MyArray is `{null, null, null}`, so `MyArray[0] == null`

```
MyArray[0] = new TestClass(42, "42");
```

MyArray is `{anObject, null, null}`

```
MyArray[0].testint = 3; // this is valid
```

Comment: When I try this I get error CS1729 on this line:

`MyArray[0] = new TestClass();`

Comment: You don't have en empty constructor, so you can't call TestClass() without argument. You can either add an empty constructor to your TestClass(), or give parameter to the constructor to match the signature of your existing constructor.

Comment: Yeah when I added an argument it compiled and ran perfectly.. I hate how this language is so tricky to get to work correctly sometimes.. Thanks anyway!